# Representing empty byte array through an Int variable?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

What value should be assigned to an integer type variable, to represent an empty byte array?  I need this to store an empty byte array in the database, to represent valueless column in Cassandra.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

According to the Cassandra API http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API An empty byte array is

```
byte[] emptyArray = new byte[0];
```

Answer (score 14):

In general Java terminology, an empty byte array is a byte array with length zero, and can be created with the Java expression `new byte[0]`.  The Casandra API uses the standard terminology.

While is is technically possible (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750734/could-we-save-space-by-representing-small-byte-arrays-as-integers)) to represent a byte array using an integer typed variable, it wouldn't work here because the Casandra API doesn't support that kind of thing.  (And neither should it ...)

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125390/139985) explains how you *should* represent an empty byte array when using the Casandra APIs.

Answer (score 8):

In java, you can create a new array by providing just the length of the desired array

> `new type[length]`

```
private byte[] getByteResponse() {
    return new byte[0];
}
```

This should do.

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)